# algebraic derivation of sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I've seen the standard combinatorial and algebraic proofs that $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}=2^n$, where the algebraic proof uses induction and Pascal's identity: $${n\choose k}+{n\choose k+1}={n+1\choose k+1}$$

My question is: is there any algebraic proof of the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}=2^n$ that doesn't use that identity and induction? More specifically, is there some factoring trick (or some other method) that would allow you to directly show that, for example, $\frac{4!}{4!0!}+\frac{4!}{3!1!}+\frac{4!}{2!2!}+\frac{4!}{1!3!}+\frac{4!}{4!0!}=2^4$ (that would generalize to other values of n)?

(My first thought was to just 'unwind' the inductive proof, but that just leads to $1+1+...+1$ with $2^n$ terms, which isn't very enlightening.)

Comment: $2^n=(1+1)^n=$ ...

Answer (score 1):

**Combinatorial argument:**

$\displaystyle\binom nk$ counts the number of ways to write numbers made of $k$ zeroes and $n-k$ ones. Hence the sum on all $k$ counts the number of $n$-bits binary numbers.

$$000\,|\,001,010,100\,|\,011,101,110\,|\,111$$

Answer (score 0):

> We can apply the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)* and obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}1^k1^{n-k}=(1+1)^n\color{blue}{=2^n}
> \end{align*}